# Track sub-directory folders respectively

Tags: google-analytics

I've never used Google Analytics before, and I'm now tasked with setting it up for my client. However I have no idea how to make this work, so I must ask you.

What I need to accomplish is have the GA show separate analysis of multiple(and separate) websites based on its' directory.

For e.g., URLs below all shows different content based on its' final URL:

```
http://url/PM/201908/20190822234813298/EB/Type-1/start_here.html
http://url/PM/201908/20190822234813298/EB/Type-2/start_here.html
http://url/PM/201908/20190822234813298/EB/Type-3/start_here.html
http://url/PM/201908/20190822234813298/EB/Type-4/start_here.html
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is preset directory
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is automatically set depending on date and time
                                         ^^^^^^^^ This is the starting directory
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ index.html
```

For maintenance purposes, I need to use only one GA track ID while showing different analysis for each for the `Type-n` folders.

Is there a method to achieve this? I'd greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Content Grouping** option: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en and extract pages with regex capture groups by Page URL.